# How to create and use an Android Library within existing project

Tags: android, android-library

I have an existing android project `project one`, in which I want to  add a feature lets say `SpecialToast`. Instead of adding it to the project directly, I want to create this feature as an `android library` so it can be used in other projects `project two`.

I am a bit confused on the procedure how to create.

I have gone through https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library and I tried to create a library within `project one` which does create a library.

New -> New module -> Android library

what is the right procedure

1. Create a brand new android application and in that application create a new Android library.
2. In `Project one` create a new android library.

If option 2 is correct, once I create a android library within `project one` how can I use it in `project one`

If option 1 is correct, how can I publish that and test easily with `project one`

Thanks
R

Update
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both options are possible.
You can create the library module in a separate project and build and export it from there (your option 1). You can export your library by using the gradle wrapper task `assemble`. For example, if your library module is called `brdroid`, execute this from your project's root folder:

```
./gradlew brdroid:assembleRelease
```

This will create the `brdroid-release.aar` file in the folder `{project root}/brdroid/build/outputs/aar`.
You can then either copy the aar file to another project or upload it to a package manager. Either manually or for example with the [maven publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

If you upload it to a package manager, you can add your library as a remote dependency just like you do with other libraries by using `implementation` or `api` + your package name, artifact id and version number.

For debugging purpose it is easier to use the library module in a project directly (this is your option 2). Meaning, that an app module and library module are in the same project side by side. In this example, if both modules are in the same project, you need to add the `brdroid` module as a dependency to `project one` by adding this in the `project one` `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation project(':brdroid')
```

Note, that you can still export your library as an aar file and publish it like in option 1.

And in this scenario, it's still possible to keep the library module in a separate project and repository and add it to your app's git-repository and project by using [git-submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). This is a little bit more.

### Using git submodules

An example usage of git-submodules can look like this: Let's consider we have this two projects which are in separate git repositories:

- `My Library` which has only the `brdroid` android library module
- `MyApplication` which has only the `app` android application module:

[image: My Library project structure]
[image: MyApplication project structure]

In order to add the `MyLibrary` repository as a git-submodule to the `MyApplication` git repository, execute this from the `MyApplication` root folder:

```
git submodule add -b master https://{url-to-My-Library-git-repository}
```

The `-b master` only tells which branch to track. You can change it.

This clones `My Library` into a new subfolder which is not tracked by the `MyApplication` repository. It also creates two changes which you need to commit in order to make them permanent.

Next, open `settings.gradle` from the `MyApplication` root folder and add the brdroid module to the `MyApplication` project by changing the first row from:

```
include ':app'
```

to

```
include ':app', 'MyLibrary:brdroid'
```

`MyLibrary` is just the folder in which the `brdroid` module resides.

Also, add `brdroid` as a dependency to the `app` module by adding this to the build.gradle file of the app module:

```
implementation project(':MyLibrary:brdroid')
```

Your result should now look like this:

[image: Result in Android Studio]

Now, `app` and `brdroid` are in the same project but the development of `brdroid` happens in a separate git repository.

Comment: Hi @Alexander Hoffmann, thank you so much for responding and giving a nice explanation, I am in favour of option 2 of having `library project` within `project one` as it is easier to debug as you said. will try that

Comment: Also in the last paragraph you mentioned regarding keeping the `library project` in a separate project and repository. Yes I want to have this as a separate repositiory in GitHub. how can I achieve that. will that change the way I create `android library` within `project one`

Comment: Hey thanks you are suggesting to use `library project` as a separate app and follow git submodules process to add it to `project one`?

Comment: i thought u said to use `library project` within `project one`

Comment: With submodules your combining both. The library repository contains just the library in a own project. The app project imports the library directly as a module which lays next to the app module for easier debugging.

Comment: okay, also i created a library as you suggested and added this line `implementation project(':brdroid')` in app gradle but it did work. i get the error `':app@stagingDebugProxyUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :brdroid.`

Comment: Brdroid is the name of your library? Is there a brdroid folder inside the root of your project? Does settings.gradle include brdroid?

Comment: actually my library name is `offlineservicelibrary` yes it is in settings.gradle. In app build.gradle. i also tried `implementation project('::offlineservicelibrary')` and in settings its `include ':offlineservicelibrary'` i have added a screenshot of how it looks